How do I use the onbeforecopy and oncopy events in a Razor component?
Per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.eventhandlers
There are event handlers for copying text, on copy and onbeforecopy. It appears to work similarly to onclick and the like. However I cannot find a single example of their use, nor can I make them work.
How do I use them?

Maybe show the code that isn't working. It's not clear if you don't know how to use events in general, or if there's something specific you want to do and aren't sure which event would be the best to use.

You could try following sample. Just note that these events only work with interactive rendermode, not in SSR.
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div @oncopy="HandleCopy" @onbeforecopy="HandleBeforeCopy">
    This text can be copied. Try selecting it and pressing Ctrl+C.
</div>
@code {
    private void HandleBeforeCopy(EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Action Before copy to clipboard");
    }
    private void HandleCopy(ClipboardEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Content was copied to the clipboard!");
    }
}

